# Eclipse GUI testing tool?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, automated-tests, jface

what do you use for automatic GUI testing an eclipse rcp app?

I checked [Xored Q7](http://www.xored.com/products/q7/) which looks pretty awesome, but it doesn't work 100%, the same goes for [froglogic squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/). I need something for testing SWT/JFACE and GEF(but i could live without GEF support). Is there any other mature testing tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in charge of [Xored's Q7](http://www.xored.com/products/q7/) development, and we'll be very interesting learning more about your test case (where Q7 does not work 100% perfectly). Can you please email me or Xored support and I'm pretty sure we'll resolve that problems very fast.

Thank you,
Andrey

Comment: I ended up using Xored Q7 and it works without issues right now.

Answer (score 3):

[SWTBot](http://swtbot.com/) is designed to test eclipse RCP (SWT&JFace) applications. It is still [in incubation](http://eclipse.org/swtbot/) though. The last time I used it, it had some issues, but it's almost 3 years back, so I hope the maintainers have made some progress.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using SWTBot in the last year and it works fine. You must know that there is no record function, but writing the tests per hand isn't so difficult.There are some limitations regarding native dialogs, which cannot be tested using SWTBot.

There are another two GUI test frameworks from Bredex - [Jubula](http://www.bredex.de/web/index.php/guidancer_jubula_en.html) / [GUIDancer](http://www.bredex.de/web/index.php/guidancer_jubula_en.html). Last year I have tried the Jubula, but without success to understand how it works.